# Creating a socket that uses whois

Tags: java, sockets

Here is a program that I got from `Java Complete Reference: 7th Edition`. It is slightly modified:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WhoIs {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Socket s = new Socket("internic.net",43);

        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        String domain = "facebook.com"+"\n";
        byte[] stringToByte = domain.getBytes();
        os.write(stringToByte);

        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String temp;
        while((temp=buf.readLine())!="\n"){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

It just contacts `internic.net` and gets information about Facebook. However, the socket won't connect. I get an exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javacomplete.WhoIs.main(WhoIs.java:8)
```

Everything is exactly the same as in the book **except** the reading the data back. I used a `BufferedReader` and the book used `InputStream` to read single characters.

Help! Why won't it connect ??

Comment: Next time, please at least read the error message before posting.

Comment: @Celada I did and I could not get why the example worked in the book and not when I executed it. Sorry, I am a n00b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct host name is `whois.internic.net` and not `internic.net`:

```
$ telnet internic.net 43
Trying 192.0.43.9...
telnet: connect to address 192.0.43.9: Connection refused
Trying 2001:500:88:200::9...
telnet: connect to address 2001:500:88:200::9: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

$ telnet whois.internic.net 43
Trying 199.7.56.74...
Connected to whois.internic.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Thanks you, that worked perfectly for me. I assume that there is an error in the book ? The address is as-is from the book :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can clearly see from the "Connection refused" error, there is no WHOIS server running on `internic.net` port 43.

Which WHOIS server do you want to contact? Most domain registrars run a WHOIS server, many of the ccTLD operators also run one (e.g. `whois.cira.ca` for the `ca` ccTLK), all of the RIRs (ARIN, RIPE, etc...) run one, there is one at `whois.internic.net` for the gTLD registry, etc, etc...